# Can't access to React Context

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I recently try to implement context in my React app but I just can't access to my context on a chlid component.

The principle is as follows:
The **index.js** provide a context who declare a value which correspond to the logged status of an user (**false** by default).

If **App.js** detects a JWT store in the localstorage, so the context is updated to **true** and a certain component is render.

Here is the Code:

**AppContext.js**

```
import React from 'react'

export const AppContext = React.createContext({
  isUserLogged: false
})
```

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import './assets/sakura/app.css'
import App from './components/App'
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker'
import { AppContext } from './context/AppContext'

ReactDOM.render((
  <AppContext.Provider>
      <App />
  </AppContext.Provider>
), document.getElementById('root'));
```

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import Auth from './auth/Auth'
import Main from './main/Main'
import { AppContext } from '../context/AppContext'

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
        userToken: localStorage.getItem('spotlight-token'),
        isUserLogged: false
    }
}

UNSAFE_componentWillMount() {
    if (this.state.userToken) this.setState({isUserLogged: true})
}

static contextType = AppContext


render() {
    console.log(this.context)

    const isUserLogged = this.state.isUserLogged

    return isUserLogged ? <Main /> : <Auth />
}
}

export default App
```

But the problem is here, the console returns **undefined** and I don't understand why.

Thank you for your help, I know it may sound slightly stupid but I'm a pure beginner width context and really want to understand it.

Comment: Your provider doesn't have a value

Comment: Okay but the value aren't those passed in the AppContext.js ?

Comment: @RenaudMonell That's the default value, in case you forget to render a Provider. When you render a Provider, you should pass in the value you want via its value prop. Currently you don't have that prop, so you're specifying undefined.

Comment: Thank you very much ! 
This notion was a little cloudy now it remains for me to find how to change its value and I would be good!

Comment: @RenaudMonell pass it in as a prop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the example at the [official docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#updating-context-from-a-nested-component) under the heading Updating Context from a Nested Component:

app.js

```
import {ThemeContext, themes} from './theme-context';
import ThemeTogglerButton from './theme-toggler-button';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.toggleTheme = () => {
      this.setState(state => ({
        theme:
          state.theme === themes.dark
            ? themes.light
            : themes.dark,
      }));
    };

    // State also contains the updater function so it will
    // be passed down into the context provider
    this.state = {
      theme: themes.light,
      toggleTheme: this.toggleTheme,
    };
  }

  render() {
    // The entire state is passed to the provider
    return (
      <ThemeContext.Provider value={this.state}>
        <Content />
      </ThemeContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}

function Content() {
  return (
    <div>
      <ThemeTogglerButton />
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.root);
```

theme-toggler-button.js

```
import {ThemeContext} from './theme-context';

function ThemeTogglerButton() {
  // The Theme Toggler Button receives not only the theme
  // but also a toggleTheme function from the context
  return (
    <ThemeContext.Consumer>
      {({theme, toggleTheme}) => (
        <button
          onClick={toggleTheme}
          style={{backgroundColor: theme.background}}>
          Toggle Theme
        </button>
      )}
    </ThemeContext.Consumer>
  );
}

export default ThemeTogglerButton;
```